# Can the following test conditon be simplified

Tags: linux, unix, testing

I have a variable a, if I echo it it gives me.

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 16 2014 ggo -> /export/s1/home/ggo
```

The following code checks if the owner or group is a number or root. If either the owner or group is a number or root, then it will print the name of directory, in this case ggo.

```
if [[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$3}") =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$3}") == root ]] || [[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$4}") =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$4}") == root ]] ; then echo $(echo $a | awk "{print \$9}"); fi;
```

However can it be simplified?

For example cant the following section be condensed:

```
[[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$3}") =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ $(echo $a|awk "{print \$3}") == root ]]
```

Comment: If you're looking for files owned by uids with no corresponding user, `find dir -nouser -print`

Comment: Probably is better to go to the root of the problem and instead of the output of `ls -l file`, get something better selected with `stat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the commenters on your question that there may be a better way overall to do what you want to do, to solve this with a single command that is more simplified, you could move your IF statement into awk:

```
echo $a | awk ' ($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $3=="root" || $4 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $4=="root") {print $9}'
```

Comment: Would be good to group the conditions within parentheses to make it more clear. Also, note `$3="root"` assigns the value `root` to `$3`. You probably mean `$3=="root"`.

Comment: Note also regex comparison work with `~`, not `==`: `awk 'BEGIN {a="234"; if (a~/^[0-9]*$/) print "yes"}'`. So `$3` and `$4`'s comparisons should also be corrected.

Comment: So close, yet so far away.... I've corrected for that as well. Thank you, @fedorqui

Comment: This works, but where is the IF statement? How does bash know that it is an IF?

Comment: Any thing returning Boolean results before a command block like `{print $9}` is used as a condition. If the awk command were more complex then I would explicitly state the IF to avoid confusion. Equivalent statement with an if would be `echo $a | awk ' { if ($3 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $3=="root" || $4 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ || $4=="root") print $9}'`